# java - is big fat jar a common practise in Java or junior dev concept?

Tags: java

I have a java application, all dependency jars are stored in a separate folder, all jars folder size is over 80mb. Is it a common practice to create a big fat jar of 80mb size instead? Will it be professional concept or is it not good?

Comment: I don't think there is a common practice with regard to this. Some people do it one way, other people do it the other way. Having just one file might be more convenient than a directory full of jar files. If you use Maven you can use the [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to build a single jar with all dependencies included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minecraft server executable is a big `.jar`. I'm willing to bet that they're better Java programmers than I am, so I would not feel like a novice packaging my app in a big jar. Sorry I don't have something better than anecdotal input.

Comment: As you put it: anecdotal evidence is not proof. There are many example of the opposite.

Comment: If anything, that speaks to it being dependent on the application of the Java solution. We don't have much context.

Answer (score 1):

A .jar is only a packaging of a library. Resulting size is not a design matter: you should think about which components are you planning to reuse in other applications, or the architecture you chose to build your app. If there was no previous planning about what the app would become in the future, you will find in the future the need of splitting it in several modules. 
Don't get obsessed with it, but keep always in mind the big picture: it will avoid you future problems.

Choosing a methodology to design your solutions will help you a lot. There's a lot of literature out there: just search for the right one for your problem.